# RASA bots response in Facebook messenger as button (postback) but click not working

Tags: bots, chatbot, facebook-messenger, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have worked around with RASA + FB messenger. 
I'm able to interact with bots on messenger as normal. But when it comes to response as Button (postback). It's not working as I tried to click on response button from bots. If I type it do work. 
I check on logs, and local webhook but it got no interaction. 
Anyone experience such a case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you subscribed to postback webhook event in your Developers account?
If not, you have to subscribe for that to receive the postback events. 
See the reference: [messaging_postbacks Webhook Event Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_postbacks)

Comment: Yes, It's the problem with Webhook subcribe
Thank you so much